# Replacement for Cart (M2)

Tags: magento2, cart, deprecated

what's the best replace for

> \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart

since this class Cart is deprecated ?

Comment: `@deprecated 100.1.0 Use \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote instead` clearly written in the class

Answer (score 1):

You can use cart Items by two ways

1. Inject direct \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
   and get cart items
2. Inject Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
   from checkout session get Quote to get Items like that using $items = $this->session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

   ```
    class Reepaypayment {
        protected $session;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
        ) {
            $this->session = $session;
        }

        public function afterIsAvailable(
            \Radarsofthouse\Reepay\Model\Reepaypayment $subject,
            $result
        ) {
            $items = $this->session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

            return $result;
        }
   ```

   }